# Separate "Source" arguments and "Parent Script" arguments in bash

Tags: bash, arguments

I have a script that parses arguments from its parents script.

script1.sh

```
echo " script1 got $# args: $@"
```

script2.sh

```
source script1.sh
echo "script2 got $# args: $@"
```

When I execute it I get:

```
$ bash script2.sh 1 2 cat
Script1 got 3 args: 1 2 cat
Script2 got 3 args: 1 2 cat
```

However, I would like to change script2.sh to allow script1.sh to receive its own arguments.

NewScript2.sh

```
source script1.sh arg1
echo "script2 got $# args: $@"
```

Now I get

```
$ bash script2.sh 1 2 cat
Script1 got 1 args: arg1
Script2 got 3 args: 1 2 cat
```

I can fix it so I get both arguments by changing script2 to

```
source script1.sh "$@" arg1
echo "script2 got $# args: $@"
```

My question is How can I change script1 to differentiate between the arguments recieved from script1 and script2?

No matter what I do to the `$@` (quotes, curley braces etc...) it still tells me I have 4 arguments.  Same thing for how I treat the input arguments.

Example:

```
$ bash script2.sh 1 2 cat
Script1 got 4 args: arg1 1 2 cat
Script2 got 3 args: 1 2 cat
$ bash script2.sh "1 2 cat"
Script1 got 4 args: arg1 1 2 cat
Script2 got 1 args: 1 2 cat
```

Comment: `to differentiate between the arguments` - It can't. You have do it manually, setup some convention, by which you can differentiate them. Ex pass `"$@" -- arg1` - all arguments in front `--` are from script2.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, you need to use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` when you call `script1.sh` with arguments:

```
cat script2.sh
source script1.sh "$*" arg1
echo "script2 got $# args: $@"
```

Then use:

```
bash script2.sh 1 2 cat
script1 got 2 args: 1 2 cat arg1
script2 got 3 args: 1 2 cat
```

As per `man bash`:

> `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c..."`, where `c` is the first character of
>                 the value of the `IFS` variable.  If `IFS` is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.  If `IFS` is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>   Whereas `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2"`